# How to detect changes in the src property for an image object from a directive in [Angular 2]?

Tags: angularjs-directive, typescript, angular

I have an img object with a src that will change after my http request.

How can I detect a change in the property for this img inside my-custom-directive?

```
< img my-custom-directive [src]="user.photo" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do property binding for directives like this:

```
<img [my-custom-directive]="user.photo" [src]="user.photo" />
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YQVR1peTxTLYZlhrZJxF?p=preview